# Custom name for android library

Tags: android, aar

When I build an android library project in android studio, it generates artifact named 'app-debug'.

I want to know how to give it a custom name,say 'my-fantastic-library'. Second,if I include it in an android application and make a release apk for application, would there be some issues as aar's name suggests debug mode.

Comment: Right click on apk and rename it :)

Comment: that was real quick reply.Thanks a ton.I want to knon whether it can be done as part of  build process.

Comment: @Mandroid Please add an overview about your project structure and the `build.gradle` file(s)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have actually shunned the idea of having android library. Now I have the feature integrated in main application itself.